# Selective styling css3

Tags: html, css

This is my code:

```
<table width="562" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" class="genericClass">
     Some nested tags
</table>
```

and my styles are:

```
table.genericClass  a { ...  } 
table.genericClass  p,li,div,td {}
```

But all the `div`, `p` and all the listed tags are getting the styles mentioned above which is not expected. Is my syntax wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now you are selecting all the `div`, `li` and `td`'s from the DOM. If you want to add the style only to the elements inside the table with class `genericClass` your code should be:

```
table.genericClass a {
  /**your properties and values here**/
} 
table.genericClass p,
table.genericClass li,
table.genericClass div,
table.genericClass td {
  /**your properties and values here**/
}
```

Or if you want to style them separately:

```
table.genericClass p{
  /**your properties and values here**/
}
table.genericClass li{
  /**your properties and values here**/
}
table.genericClass div{
  /**your properties and values here**/
}
table.genericClass td {
  /**your properties and values here**/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try giving classes to the tags you want to style. I have created an example below:

```
<div class = "div-Class"></div>
<ul>
   <li class = "li-Class">Lorem lipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
<ul>
<p class = "para-Class">Lorem lipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class = "table-data">Lorem lipsum dolor sit amet</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Then use in your CSS stylesheet as needed. To eliminate any chance that you might give one class to a div and then you misspelled that class in your stylesheet, copy and paste that class to your stylesheet. An example is below:

```
.div-Class {
    /* Some Styles */
}

.li-Class {
   /* Some more Styles */
}

para-Class {
   /* Even more Styles */
}

table-data {
   /* Some Table Styles */
```

Hope this helps!